# Magento Entity Types are missing in "eav_entity_type" table

Tags: magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

Entity Types such as quote_item, order_item, order_type_id are missing in "eav_entity_type" table.  Because of this issue I am not able to integrate Magento Made to Order (MTO) module.  My version is 1.7.0.2.